# How to get 3D building data in map functions?

Tags: computational-geometry, map, geography, geographics

Most modern mapping APIs have 3D model data for city buildings built-in. For example:

[image]

Is there some way to get this functionality in the Geography related functions?

[image]

I believe `Geographics` and friends use OSM (Open street maps) and from their [website](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D) it looks like they have some 3D data for buildings in their maps:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

- We could incorporate additional 3d data into a `Show` of `GeoGraphics` + `Graphic3D`, but I don't know how I would go about aligning things properly.
- It looks like OSM has lots of mapping data unavailable to Geo functions like street notes, traffic patterns, and more. Is there any undocumented option or Service api for this? It would be nice to get the additional maps:

[image]

Comment: To your last point: there is an `OSMImport` `ResourceFunction` available that gets rw data: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OSMImport However, if you're looking for the different tileservers, you can just use the `GeoServer` option and search for the tileserver template URLs.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/example_scenes Given the new UnityLink we can do some nice stuff. I have also seen people hacking google map and manage to extract 3D data.